# Getting filetype in an Express route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an Express route `/doc/:id` which serves up the HTML representation of a document, and I want it to serve the EPUB representation when appended with "`.epub`". Express doesn't separate on a period, however, so if I use `/doc/:id.epub` sets `req.params.id` to "`id.epub`". Is there a way to have the file extension recognised as a separate parameter or do I simply need to use a regex to extract it?

I have looked at `res.format`, but it seems this is only effective when the `Accepted` header is set, which it would not be if the URL is simply typed into a browser, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
app.get('/doc/:filename.:ext', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

This requires that the part following `/doc/` contains at least one period, which may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the behavior you are describing, I think you might have your route matching rules out of order.

This works:

```
app.get('/doc/:id.epub', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('id: ' + req.params.id); //match /doc/x.epub (id=x)
});
app.get('/doc/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('id: ' + req.params.id); //match doc/x (id=x) | doc/y.html (id=y.html)
});
```

If /doc:/:id is first you'd get an id of x.epub for /doc/x.epub.